# Magento 2: Rewrite category URLs programmatically

Tags: magento2, category, url

I want to remove category ids from category URLs and replace them with the current category or subcategory name.

Is this possible?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try this module https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to replace it programmatically.
Please check the admin settings.

- Admin->Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Search Engine
  Optimization
- Catalog->Categories->Select Category->Search Engine Optimization

After updating them, you have to flush the caches and run the reindex.